# Load facebook php sdk problem

Tags: facebook

I am trying to load the facebook php sdk in the wordpress template. I've added the code to the header.php file:

```
    locate_template( 'facebook/facebook.php', true );

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => appid,
     'secret' => appsecret
));

$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

if ( isset($signedRequest['app_data']) )
{
    echo $signedRequest['app_data'];    
}
```

But I get get this error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent..
```

How can I load the facebook sdk before any other file is loaded

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add functionality to themes. Or even worse: To templates. Wrap it up in a plugin and load the plugins bootstrap on `plugins_loaded`, or - in case of a mu-plugin - on `muplugins_loaded`.

In every case, you shouldn't throw around with globals. Just add your output to a custom filter or hook and only add this one to your template: (Example) `do_action( 'facebook_app_data' );`